# Why is app-routing module failing to route?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I think I've set up structure correctly per Angular Heros tutorial but getting

> "`cannot match any routes`" error.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
const routes: Routes = [{path: 'home',component: HomeComponent}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<p>home works!</p>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what route are you trying to access? http://localhost:4200/home or just http://localhost:4200?

Comment: localhost:4200 should default to localhost:4200/home

Comment: Anyway, I got it working a while back.  I had to start over using a working example, then gradually add my code into it.  Looking at the final code, I don't see why my original attempt didn't work.  It looks the same.